# How can I create a signed uninstaller with InnoSetup (ISCC.exe) and DigiCert's smctl.exe?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, signtool, digicert

I use smctl.exe to sign a desktop application on our build server.
I call execute iscc.exe with my *.iss file including /S parameter like this:

```
/Dsigning=true /Dbuildworkingdir=${bamboo.build.working.directory} ${bamboo.build.working.directory}\150_Software\10_SW\InnoSetup\EPCSetup.iss "/Ssigntool=smctl.exe sign --keypair-alias key_XXXXXXXX --input $f"
```

This results in a properly signed "setup.exe".

This works as long as I have this line in my *.iss file:

```
SignedUninstaller=no
```

As soon as it is switched to `SignedUninstaller=yes`, the build fails.

Here is the corresponding excerpt from the Bamboo Log:

```
build   27-Sep-2023 08:09:20    Preparing Setup program executable
build   27-Sep-2023 08:09:20       Updating version info (SETUP.E32)
build   27-Sep-2023 08:09:21       Running Sign Tool signtool: C:\Program Files\DigiCert\DigiCert Keylocker Tools\smctl.exe sign --keypair-alias key_XXXXXXXXX --input "D:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bamboo\local-working-dir\360449\CFN-DIG-JOB1\150_Software\10_SW\InnoSetup\Output\uninst.e32.tmp"
build   27-Sep-2023 08:09:24    There were no files found for signing
error   27-Sep-2023 08:09:24    Error in D:\Atlassian\ApplicationData\Bamboo\local-working-dir\360449\CFN-DIG-JOB1\150_Software\10_SW\InnoSetup\EPCSetup.iss: The Sign Tool command returned an exit code of 0, but the file does not have a digital signature.
error   27-Sep-2023 08:09:24    Compile aborted.
```

My investigations have shown that smctl.exe uses the Microsoft signtool.exe for signing. signtool.exe can only sign executable files.

Now I can't get any further.
InnoSetup wants to sign "uninst.e32.tmp" but smctl.exe refuses. Is anyone aware of this problem? What can I do?
And in addition: Why does InnoSetup try to sign a *.tmp file?

Any hints will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the actual Microsoft signtool with DigiCert by getting the SHA1 thumbprint of your DigiCert certificate, and then using:

```
...\path\to\signtool.exe sign /sha1 <thumbprint> /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 %1
```

where `%1` stands for the file to sign.

You can use signtool assuming you've already run the DigiCert setup tool `smksp_cert_sync.exe` to download its metadata about the certificates they hold in store for you. This registers them in some standard way that signtool understands. Since you're using `smctl` I assume this is already being done.

I believe you can get the thumbprint by running (Start > Run) `certmgr.msc` to see list of all certificates under "Current User \ Personal  \ Certificates".

I used to use DigiCert signing for everything including Inno uninstaller stubs and this worked fine.

Comment: I was just able to sign successfully with your instructions. The signing is, as you wrote, also able to sign *.tmp files. The integration into the InnoSetup build process was without problems.

Comment: This works great, only change I made was the %1 to $f

Answer (score 2):

The `uninst.e32.tmp` is an *executable file*, just with a `.tmp` extension.

Based on the error message, it looks like the `smctl` did not even attempt to sign the file. So the problem is not with the file itself, but possibly with its name (extension).

Renaming the file to `.exe` might resolve the problem. You can write a script (a simple batch file will do) that renames the file, signs it, and renames it back. And configure that script/batch as a sign tool in Inno Setup.

For some examples of such batch file, see

- [Replace "Setup/Uninstall" string in UAC prompt for Inno Setup uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69554187/850848#69556853) or
- [Microsoft SmartScreen - suspended using Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29067877/850848#29072495)

Comment: It took me a little while to get the batch file running. I don't have much experience with it and the test cycles on the build server are a bit tedious. Signing the uninstaller now works. Unfortunately there is still a follow up problem with "SignTool Error: The file is being used by another process" but the original problem is solved.